# What is good halal chatting with girlfriend or watching porn?

Tags: halal-haram, pornography

Assalam o Alikum.

Sir when I chat with the girl I wish to marry, I don't  fall in prey of pornography.I promised her no to leave.But last week I left her because of Islam .Now I'm prey of pornography.Please help. Is chatting with her in this situation halal or haram.

Answer (score 1):

[Is it permissible to have a girlfriend without having physical contact with her?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13172/is-it-permissible-to-have-a-girlfriend-without-having-physical-contact-with-her)

Pornography is Haram in Ramzan and without Ramzan so there is no relaxation in case of pornography.

This question is already done see the link above.Hope this will help you.Thanks

Comment: But sir there is no mention of pornography there. My situation is different. Please do read my details also. Past week due to that bad videos I wanted to commit suicide.Please help

Comment: i am editing my question again and then see

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Still not getting in which situation I am.