# Being friends with the opposite gender that is a muslim

Tags: friendship

So Im a muslim girl of course and i have a bestfriend which is a boy and he is really halal which in the way he prays and recites the quran is this bad?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it permissible to have a girlfriend without having physical contact with her?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/13172/is-it-permissible-to-have-a-girlfriend-without-having-physical-contact-with-her)

Answer (score 0):

On islamic terms I think you aren't supposed to be alone with him. But to have love and respect for him is not a problem. Marry him.